# How to monitor different metrics for scaling an application on Amazon

Tags: amazon-ec2, scalability, amazon-cloudwatch

Is that possible to decide about scalability based upon multiple metrics. For example, I wanna check both the "CPU Utilization" and "number of requests" together and then decide whether I need to Scale my application or not.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, I do not believe this is possible as desired based on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=223753 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94984.

You do have the avenue of using custom CloudWatch metrics as your source for scaling. So, rather than trying to use two metrics, you could create your own metric based off that other data to decide how/when to scale.

Here's the original blog post regarding the availability of [custom CloudWatch metrics](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics.html). Also, here's a post about [using AutoScaling with them](http://www.thatsgeeky.com/2012/01/autoscaling-with-custom-metrics/).

This should give you the ability to be as granular as you like in terms of what constitutes a a scalable event for your system.

Comment: what I'm wondering to know is not just a custom metric, but also to know how to decide based on more than one metric at the same time to decide for scaling. For example I like to scale-up if cpu utilization is more than 70% and memory performance is above 75% at the same time.

Comment: Right, I understand your need. However, as noted by https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=223753 and https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=94984 there is no way to do so that *I* am aware of. My recommendation to make your own metric that factors those two values in would allow you do so something like the above question.

Comment: so, do u mean that for example I monitor the CPU and Memory in my own application and then whenever the combination of both has met my scaling policy, then I publish it as a kind of custom metric to the CloudWatch to perform the scaling?

Comment: That would be my thought. It allows you the control you're looking for but keeps you within the AWS eco-system in process. Until they support multiple metrics for a single alarm, this may be your best option. Maybe someone else will come by with a better one, but for what I know, this may be the approach to run with!